# MySQL Full-Text Search Across Multiple Tables - Quick/Long Solution?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, lucene, sphinx

I have been doing a bit of research on full-text searches as we realized a series of LIKE statements are terrible. My first find was MySQL full-text searches. I tried to implement this and it worked on one table, failed when I was trying to join multiple tables, and so I consulted stackoverflow's articles (look at the end for a list of the ones I've been to)

I didn't see anything that clearly answered my questions. I'm trying to get this done literally in an hour or two (quick solution) but I also want to do a better long term solution. Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    a.`product_id`, a.`name`, a.`slug`, a.`description`, b.`list_price`, 
    b.`price`, c.`image`, c.`swatch`, e.`name` AS industry 
FROM `products` AS a 
LEFT JOIN `website_products` AS b ON (a.`product_id` = b.`product_id`)
LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT `product_id`, `image`, `swatch` FROM `product_images` 
      WHERE `sequence` = 0) AS c ON (a.`product_id` = c.`product_id`) 
LEFT JOIN `brands` AS d ON (a.`brand_id` = d.`brand_id`) 
INNER JOIN `industries` AS e ON (a.`industry_id` = e.`industry_id`) 
WHERE 
    b.`website_id` = 96 
    AND b.`status` = 1 
    AND b.`active` = 1 
    AND MATCH( a.`name`, a.`sku`, a.`description`, d.`name` ) AGAINST ( 'ashley sofa' ) 
GROUP BY a.`product_id` 
ORDER BY b.`sequence` LIMIT 0, 9
```

The error I get is: `Incorrect arguments to MATCH`

If I remove `d.name` from the `MATCH` statement it works. I have a full-text index on that column.

I saw one of the articles say to use an `OR MATCH` for this table, but won't that lose the effectiveness of being able to rank them together or match them properly?

Other places said to use `UNION`s but I don't know how to do that properly.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

---

In the idea of a long term solution it seems that either Sphinx or Lucene is best. Now by no means and I a MySQL guru, and I heard that Lucene is a bit more complicated to setup, any recommendations or directions would be great.

Articles:

[MySQL full text search across multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117005/mysql-full-text-search-across-multiple-tables)
[MySQL FULLTEXT Search Across >1 Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668371/mysql-fulltext-search-across-1-table)
[MySQL: how to make multiple table fulltext search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378366/mysql-how-to-make-multiple-table-fulltext-search)
[Comparison of full text search engine - Lucene, Sphinx, Postgresql, MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737275/pros-cons-of-full-text-search-engine-lucene-sphinx-postgresql-full-text-searc)
[Searching across multiple tables (best practices)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059253/searching-across-multiple-tables-best-practices)

Comment: I fixed the "quick solution" problem, which can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891037/mysql-or-match-hangs-very-slow-on-multiple-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the short-term solution, I suggest creating a table of just the full-text values, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610812/mysql-full-text-search-why-am-i-getting-incorrect-arguments-to-match).

For the long-term solution, please take a look at [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). It is much easier to install than Lucene, and yet gives you most of its functionality. I have also heard good things about Sphinx, but have not personally ever used it.

Comment: Great for the long-term solution! Looks like we will probably be using it, for the short-term, however, that link simply pointed out that you can't link to 2 tables in the same MATCH, so I need to figure out how I can make it work. When I use OR MATCH it simply takes forever (freezes essentially) and comes back like 15 minutes later